# Handle directory update during DirectoryStream iteration

Tags: java

According to the [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) documentation:

> It is thread safe but does not freeze the directory while iterating,
>   so it may (or may not) reflect updates to the directory that occur
>   after the DirectoryStream is created.

So if I have a filter that accepts everything that isn't a .json file and create the DirectoryStream with it, it appears that if a .json file is added while I'm iterating through the stream, there's a chance that the iterator will grab it. Is there a way around this? Or do I just need to check for the json extension in my iteration as well?

Comment: The Javadoc is pretty explicit, and you could write a simple test to confirm that it behaves this way.  Your code will have to handle this possibility.

Comment: Yep, already tested, and it does behave this way. I just didn't know if there was another class in the nio package that I might have overlooked.